# Toggle not working with screenreader

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```js
if (screen.width > 769) {
  $(".searchIcon").on("click", function () {
    $(".searchForm").toggle("slow");
    $(".searchIcon").children().toggleClass("icon-search").toggleClass("icon-close");
    $("#SearchBox").focus();
  });
}
```

And my markup:

```html
<div class="searchContainer navbar-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">
   <button class="searchIcon" aria-label="Search" type="button">
   <i class="icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </button>
</div>
<div class="searchContainer hidden-md hidden-lg">
   <i class="icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="navbar-form navbar-right searchForm" style="display: none;">
   <label class="sr-only" for="#SearchBox">Search</label>
   <input id="SearchBox" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

When the button is clicked, the `.searchForm` container slowly toggles into view to show the search box. This works fine on desktop and mobile devices, but when navigating using a screen reader (using the built in accessibility tools on the iPad), selecting the button to click it has no effect. What am I missing here?

Comment: Widths usually have pixels, percents, etc on them, not just integers. I may br wrong pending what screen is, but can you confirm `screen.width` is returning a number and not a string?

Comment: screen.width is returning pixels, that's not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though I found my answer here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role

I changed my JS to this:

```
    if (screen.width > 769) {
        $(".searchIcon").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var pressed = e.target.getAttribute("aria-pressed") == "true";
            //change the aria-pressed value as the button is toggled:
            e.target.setAttribute("aria-pressed", pressed ? "false" : "true");
            $(".searchForm").toggle("slow");
            $(".searchIcon").children().toggleClass("icon-search").toggleClass("icon-close");
            $("#SearchBox").focus();
        });
    }
```

and my markup to this:

```
<div class="searchContainer navbar-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">
   <button class="searchIcon" aria-label="Search" type="button" aria-pressed="false">
   <i class="icon-cmich-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </button>
</div>
<div class="searchContainer hidden-md hidden-lg">
   <i class="icon-cmich-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="navbar-form navbar-right searchForm" style="display: none;">
   <label class="sr-only" for="#SearchBox">Search</label>
   <input id="SearchBox" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

I've only been using aria for the last 3 months or so, and there is still a huge learning curve here for me, but this produced the result I was expecting. The search box now slowly toggles into place just as it did with the desktop/mobile device.